# Programmatically change "Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style"

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to programmatically change "Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style." To approach the problem, I recorded a macro during which I opened the Paragraph dialog box (Page Layout > Paragraph), checked the checkbox (don't add space) and a macro during which I unchecked the checkbox (add space). Neither affects "Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style" . . . and they have identical code:

```
Sub AddSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle()
'
' AddSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle Macro
' Add space between paragraphs of the same style.
'
    With Selection.ParagraphFormat
        .LeftIndent = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .RightIndent = InchesToPoints(0)
        .SpaceBefore = 12
        .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
        .SpaceAfter = 12
        .SpaceAfterAuto = False
        .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceMultiple
        .LineSpacing = LinesToPoints(1)
        .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
        .WidowControl = True
        .KeepWithNext = False
        .KeepTogether = False
        .PageBreakBefore = False
        .NoLineNumber = False
        .Hyphenation = True
        .FirstLineIndent = InchesToPoints(-0.25)
        .OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevelBodyText
        .CharacterUnitLeftIndent = 0
        .CharacterUnitRightIndent = 0
        .CharacterUnitFirstLineIndent = 0
        .LineUnitBefore = 0
        .LineUnitAfter = 0
        .MirrorIndents = False
        .TextboxTightWrap = wdTightNone
    End With
End Sub

Sub RemoveSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle()
'
' RemoveSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle Macro
' Remove space between paragraphs of the same style.
'
    With Selection.ParagraphFormat
        .LeftIndent = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .RightIndent = InchesToPoints(0)
        .SpaceBefore = 12
        .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
        .SpaceAfter = 12
        .SpaceAfterAuto = False
        .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceMultiple
        .LineSpacing = LinesToPoints(1)
        .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
        .WidowControl = True
        .KeepWithNext = False
        .KeepTogether = False
        .PageBreakBefore = False
        .NoLineNumber = False
        .Hyphenation = True
        .FirstLineIndent = InchesToPoints(-0.25)
        .OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevelBodyText
        .CharacterUnitLeftIndent = 0
        .CharacterUnitRightIndent = 0
        .CharacterUnitFirstLineIndent = 0
        .LineUnitBefore = 0
        .LineUnitAfter = 0
        .MirrorIndents = False
        .TextboxTightWrap = wdTightNone
    End With
End Sub
```

The code produced by the macro recorder is long, so I reduced it to a minimal version that I've verified also fails to affect "Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style":

```
Sub AddSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle()
'
' AddSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle Macro
' Add space between paragraphs of the same style.
'
End Sub

Sub RemoveSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle()
'
' RemoveSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle Macro
' Remove space between paragraphs of the same style.
'
End Sub
```

I looked at [the documentation for ParagraphFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff838713.aspx) and searched for a relevant property but found nothing that works. How can I programmatically change "Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style"?

Comment: We can help you better if you post the code you tried.

Comment: You could produce the code I tried by reading my post and using the macro recorder as I had described . . . but as I had described, the recorded code left out what I wanted to do, so posting it would not help.

Comment: Hey, I'm just trying to help you get an answer. SO is not your personal help desk. You're more likely to receive a timely and *accurate* answer if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It shows that you've put forth effort. Community members are more likely to help people who have shown effort.

Comment: For posterity, I put forth the effort to provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable version of the code produced by the macro recorder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This property is connected with Style, not with Paragraph (which suggests window title where you set this property). This is code which you look for:

```
ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal").NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle = False
ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal").NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle = True
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I want to deal with the current selection. Ideally, I would stick to a small set of styles (Heading, Normal, List Paragraph) and consistently apply them, but I need to deal with messy, ad-hoc styling. To change paragraph formatting without modifying a built-in style (or creating a new style), I can use Selection.Style or fall back to the built-in dialog.

Answer (score 10):

The macro recorder recognizes changing spacing but not "Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style" (Page Layout > Paragraph). To change paragraph formatting without modifying a built-in style (or creating a new style), I can use Selection.Style:

```
Selection.Style.NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle = False
```

or fall back to the built-in dialog:

```
With Dialogs(wdDialogFormatParagraph)
    .Before = 12
    .After = 12
    .NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle = False
    .Execute
End With
```

Comment: in Word 2013 this works for me only if I set the value to `False`. Trying to set it to `True` has no effect. Any other tips?

Answer (score 0):

```
winword.ActiveDocument.Styles["Normal"].NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle = true;
winword.ActiveDocument.Styles["List Paragraph"].NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle = false;
```

On word doc press Alt+Ctl+Shift+S to check all the styles

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles on this and is looking for a C# example, this is what worked for me. Hope it helps someone else.

```
        string signaturesPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Microsoft\Signatures\";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(signaturesPath + "Test");

        Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
        //oWord.Visible = true;
        Word.Document oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add();

        //Insert a paragraph at the beginning of the document.
        Word.Paragraph paragraph1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add();

        object oStyleName1 = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal;
        //NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle set on style then assign to doc 
        oWord.ActiveDocument.Styles[oStyleName1].NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle = true;
       
        //Setting style on paragraph here
        paragraph1.Format.set_Style(oStyleName1);
        paragraph1.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
        paragraph1.Range.InsertAfter("Testing 123");

        //Save as htm
        object htmlFormat = (int)Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML;
        oDoc.SaveAs2(signaturesPath + @"\test.htm", htmlFormat);

        oWord.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but in case more searches find this, try hacking the following:

```
Sub SetDontAddSpaceBetween()
    Dim blNoSpace As Long '(not boolean) "True" does not work; use 1
    
    'The next line is the only way to read it for the current selection.
    blNoSpace = Dialogs(wdDialogFormatParagraph).NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle
    
    MsgBox "Selection; Don't add space between...:" & CBool(blNoSpace)
    
    'How to set it for the current selection.
    With Dialogs(wdDialogFormatParagraph)
        .NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle = 0 'Check the box if true
        .Execute 'This sets it.
    End With
 
End Sub
```