# How to remove background color of copied code snippet text during paste operation on Microsoft Word preserving color format and syntax highlighting?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using Office 2016. I have copied some text from the Microsoft website from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-8.0). The code snippet on the Microsoft website is formatted with a grey background. Now when I copy this text and paste that to a Microsoft Word document, I want the copied text foreground color and want to remove the grey background color during the paste operation.  Is there any way to do this?
[image]

This is my problem

[image]

Comment: Because I can't find any option to do this from existing options in Word, maybe if some macro or VBA code can listen to the paste operation (like CRTL+V) on Word and do the formatting while I perform paste operation

Comment: VBA has no way to “listen to the paste operation”. Unless you want to remove all the formatting when you paste you will have to live with removing the shading afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a VBA script that performs the below function on press of CTRL+V. You can comment out the function that you don't want in your VBA script. I am not a VBA programmer and just created this solution using ChatGPT, MSDN help, StackOverflow and lots of hit-and-try. Hopefully, It might help others in future!

**Note:** If for some reason you don't want VBA script to execute during Paste then you can always paste by right-click `paste` option from content menu or you can assign some custom key combination for this customised paste to run from VBA.

- ApplyDocumentDefaultNormalStyleForFontAndParagraph
- ApplyNoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyleRule
- RemoveBackgroundColor
- ChangeFontColorToBlackForLightColorFont
- SetTableWidthAndBorders

It performs all the above tasks as a single unit, so if you press CTRL+Z to undo all pasted text, it is deleted as a single operation.
I have explained `how to set up VBA script` in Word document [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77228498/is-there-any-way-to-make-a-word-macro-to-automatically-format-pasted-text-into-t/78124589#78124589)

Here is the VBA script code after applying some suggestions from *Timothy Rylatt*

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_Open()
    With Application.KeyBindings.Add(WdKeyCategory.wdKeyCategoryCommand, "PasteAndFormatText", BuildKeyCode(WdKey.wdKeyControl, WdKey.wdKeyV))
    
    End With
End Sub


Private Sub Document_Close()
' Reset the CTRL+V key combination when the document is closed
    Application.KeyBindings.ClearAll
End Sub

Sub PasteAndFormatText()
    Dim oUndo As UndoRecord
    Set oUndo = Application.UndoRecord
    
    ' Begin the custom undo unit
    oUndo.StartCustomRecord "Paste and Format"
    
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim startPos As Long
    
    ' Store the start position
    startPos = Selection.Start
    
    ' Paste the content from the clipboard
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
    
    ' Extend the selection from the start position to the current selection end
    Selection.SetRange Start:=startPos, End:=Selection.End
    
    ' Now, with the pasted content selected, change its formatting
    ' Apply `No Spacing` style to the selection
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("No Spacing")
    
    ApplyDocumentDefaultNormalStyleForFontAndParagraph
    
    RemoveBackgroundColor
        
    ChangeFontColorToBlackForLightColorFont
    
    SetTableWidthAndBorders
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' End the custom undo unit
    oUndo.EndCustomRecord
End Sub

Sub RemoveBackgroundColor()
    ' Remove background color from the pasted text
    With Selection.Font
        With .Shading
            .Texture = wdTextureNone
            .ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
            .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
        End With
    End With
End Sub


Sub ApplyDocumentDefaultNormalStyleForFontAndParagraph()
    Dim para As Paragraph

    ' Now, with the pasted content selected, change its formatting for Paragraph and font
    
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font.Name   ' Change font name as needed
        .Size = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font.Size   ' Change font size as needed
    End With
    
    ' Loop through paragraphs and set spacing
    For Each para In Selection.Paragraphs
        para.SpaceBefore = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore
        para.SpaceAfter = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter
        para.LineSpacingRule = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule
    Next para
    
End Sub


Sub ChangeFontColorToBlackForLightColorFont()
'If light font(like white, yellow etc) on dark background and if we remove background the light color text is not visible, so change font to black.
    Dim char As Range
    
    ' Loop through each character in the selection
    For Each char In Selection.Characters
        ' Check if the font color is light then change it to black. We will check for 1'st char only for efficiency.
        If IsColorLight(char.Font.color) Then
            char.Font.color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next char
End Sub

Function IsColorLight(color As Long) As Boolean
    Dim R As Long, G As Long, B As Long
    Dim Y As Double ' Luminance
    
    ' Extract the RGB components from the color
    R = color Mod 256
    G = (color \ 256) Mod 256
    B = (color \ 65536) Mod 256
    
    ' Calculate the luminance
    Y = 0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B
    
    ' Check if the luminance exceeds a certain threshold for "lightness"
    ' Adjust the threshold value if necessary. A common starting point is around 186, based on the formula's maximum output of 255
    If Y > 186 Then
        IsColorLight = True
    Else
        IsColorLight = False
    End If
End Function

Sub SetTableWidthAndBorders()
    'If your selection has tables then show all borders and set table width to be within print margin
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim pageWidth As Single, leftMargin As Single, rightMargin As Single
    Dim tableWidth As Single
    
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    ' Assuming the page setup is consistent across the document
    With doc.PageSetup
        pageWidth = .pageWidth
        leftMargin = .leftMargin
        rightMargin = .rightMargin
    End With
    
    ' Calculate available width for the table
    tableWidth = pageWidth - leftMargin - rightMargin
    
    ' Check each table in the document
    For Each tbl In doc.Tables
        ' Check if the table is within the current selection
        If (tbl.Range.Start >= Selection.Start And tbl.Range.End <= Selection.End) Then
            
            ' Set table preferred width
            tbl.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints ' Set the width in points
            tbl.PreferredWidth = tableWidth ' Set the width to the calculated tableWidth
            
            ' Adjust table borders
            With tbl.Borders
                .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                .InsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth025pt
                .OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth025pt
                .InsideColor = wdColorAutomatic
                .OutsideColor = wdColorAutomatic
            End With
        End If
    Next tbl
End Sub
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: The routines ApplyDocumentDefaultNormalStyleForFontAndParagraph and ApplyNoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyleRule were clearly written by ChatGPT. Although they may apply the formatting you want, the way it is applied is illogical, to say the least. It may be the most idiotic code I have ever seen.

Comment: Hi Timothy ApplyNoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyleRule() was not from ChatGPT but from the StackOverflow site from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418243/programmatically-change-dont-add-space-between-paragraphs-of-the-same-style/77566965#77566965 

Also, ApplyDocumentDefaultNormalStyleForFontAndParagraph was partly taken from ChatGpt for enumerating the paragraphs. Please Help by correcting the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with VBA (You could do it by hand but word is strange there I think):

```
Sub RemoveAll()
With ActiveDocument.Range.Font
 With .Shading
            .Texture = wdTextureNone
            .ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
            .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
        End With

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to answer posted by Hemendr.

The code to apply formatting from the Normal style is simply idiotic. Instead of copying settings from the Normal style and applying them to the selection all that is required is to apply the style.

However, if the appropriate style is applied before pasting, which is what you would do if using the UI instead of code, then it is unnecessary to make formatting changes afterwards. In the code below the style "No Spacing" is applied as it already has the required characteristics. NOTE: style names are language dependent.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_Open()
    With Application.KeyBindings.Add(WdKeyCategory.wdKeyCategoryCommand, "PasteAndFormatText", BuildKeyCode(WdKey.wdKeyControl, WdKey.wdKeyV))
    
    End With
End Sub


Private Sub Document_Close()
' Reset the CTRL+V key combination when the document is closed
    Application.KeyBindings.ClearAll
End Sub

Sub PasteAndFormatText()
    Dim oUndo As UndoRecord
    Set oUndo = Application.UndoRecord
    
    ' Begin the custom undo unit
    oUndo.StartCustomRecord "Paste and Format"
    
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim startPos As Long
    
    ' Store the start position
    startPos = Selection.Start
    
    'Set the style first to achieve the required formatting
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("No Spacing")
    
    ' Paste the content from the clipboard
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
    
    ' Extend the selection from the start position to the current selection end
    Selection.SetRange Start:=startPos, End:=Selection.End
    
    'No need for this as all done before paste
    ' Now, with the pasted content selected, change its formatting
    'ApplyDocumentDefaultNormalStyleForFontAndParagraph
    
    'ApplyNoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyleRule
    
    RemoveBackgroundColor
        
    ChangeFontColorToBlackForLightColorFont
    
    SetTableWidthAndBorders
    
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveStart Unit:=wdLine ' This moves the insertion point to the start of the line
    
    ' Add a new paragraph (new line) after the current position
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' End the custom undo unit
    oUndo.EndCustomRecord
    

End Sub

Sub RemoveBackgroundColor()
    ' Remove background color from the pasted text
    With Selection.Font
        With .Shading
            .Texture = wdTextureNone
            .ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
            .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub ChangeFontColorToBlackForLightColorFont()
'If light font(like white, yellow etc) on dark background and if we remove background the light color text is not visible, so change font to black.
    Dim char As Range
    
    ' Loop through each character in the selection
    For Each char In Selection.Characters
        ' Check if the font color is light then change it to black. We will check for 1'st char only for efficiency.
        If IsColorLight(char.Font.color) Then
            char.Font.color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next char
End Sub

Function IsColorLight(color As Long) As Boolean
    Dim R As Long, G As Long, B As Long
    Dim Y As Double ' Luminance
    
    ' Extract the RGB components from the color
    R = color Mod 256
    G = (color \ 256) Mod 256
    B = (color \ 65536) Mod 256
    
    ' Calculate the luminance
    Y = 0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B
    
    ' Check if the luminance exceeds a certain threshold for "lightness"
    ' Adjust the threshold value if necessary. A common starting point is around 186, based on the formula's maximum output of 255
    If Y > 186 Then
        IsColorLight = True
    Else
        IsColorLight = False
    End If
End Function

Sub SetTableWidthAndBorders()
    'If your selection has tables then show all borders and set table width to be within print margin
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim pageWidth As Single, leftMargin As Single, rightMargin As Single
    Dim tableWidth As Single
    
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    ' Assuming the page setup is consistent across the document
    With doc.PageSetup
        pageWidth = .pageWidth
        leftMargin = .leftMargin
        rightMargin = .rightMargin
    End With
    
    ' Calculate available width for the table
    tableWidth = pageWidth - leftMargin - rightMargin
    
    ' Check each table in the document
    For Each tbl In doc.Tables
        ' Check if the table is within the current selection
        If (tbl.Range.Start >= Selection.Start And tbl.Range.End <= Selection.End) Then
            
            ' Set table preferred width
            tbl.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints ' Set the width in points
            tbl.PreferredWidth = tableWidth ' Set the width to the calculated tableWidth
            
            ' Adjust table borders
            With tbl.Borders
                .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                .InsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth025pt
                .OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth025pt
                .InsideColor = wdColorAutomatic
                .OutsideColor = wdColorAutomatic
            End With
        End If
    Next tbl
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Timothy thanks for your suggestions. I can remove the ApplyNoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyleRule as your code will handle it. But If I remove  ApplyDocumentDefaultNormalStyleForFontAndParagraph the script does not apply the font and font size that I set for Normal Style. to my pasted text. The pasted text has now the font and font size of the copied text.  Also, I have to add the line Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("No Spacing") after pasting the clipboard selection, if I apply it before pasting the selection then it is not working. I am using Office 2016.

Comment: @Hemendr - whether you apply "No Spacing" before or after the paste it still makes more sense than to use that other code. When you write code for Word the code should simply replicate the actions you would take in the UI.